# unable to resolve MongoDB error on Windows 8

Tags: windows, mongodb

There are quite many threads asking about this issue, but i don't see any working solution for this.

I am new with mongoDB, ive basiclly created the data,log,mongodb folders and a config file
while trying to run the db by using 'mongo' command i get the following error:
[image]

Hope anyone could help me, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i have solved this matter in the following way:

- I have deleted the entire mongodb folder.
- created a new folder all over again and put mongodb inside it so the folder hirarchy is now
- Mongodb (root)
- bin folder
- data\db

opened 2 command lines, 
one the first i used the 'mongod' command (to start the server)
on the second i used the 'mongo' command (to open a connection)

Thats it